# Poll SCM option gets overriden with every run build (with pipeline)

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I recently changed my build to use Jenkins Pipeline plugin. And it's really cool. I configured it to store Jenkins file in Git repository. I checked "Poll SCM" option and configured it to poll SCM every 15 minutes.

The problem is that the job is never run... And if I run it manually (click on the button) the Poll SCM option gets unchecked and the schedule field is emptied. I checked that with every run the config.xml file is overriden.

EDIT

In "Build Triggers" section I have "Poll SCM" selected with `H/15 * * * *` in schedule field

In Pipeline section I chose "Pipeline script from SCM"

In Jenkinsfile I tried:

```
git url: 'ssh://git@.../repo.git'
```

and

```
git poll: true, url: 'ssh://git@.../repo.git'
```

but neither of options worked.

Comment: How is your project configured ? Do you have a simple inline pipeline or are you using `Pipeline script from SCM` ? I don't understand how you load your Jenkinsfile, because if you load it using `Pipeline script from SCM` you shouldn't need to issue the `git poll...` command as your repository would be automatically checked out. Can you provide more info please ?

Comment: I added the details to the question. I also thought that I don't need to configure poll in the script just in the build configuration. 
What does it mean it will be automatically checked out? Only if I have a schedule set, right?

Comment: Is your Jenkins file in the same repo than the one you where you have your code ? If so, just configuring `Pipeline script from SCM` (yes, with a schedule set) is enough and Jenkins will automatically checkout your code each time it looks (every 15 minutes) if a change has been made to your repo since the last check, so you don't need to issue a a `git poll...`. Say you have just a `echo "Hello"`in your Jenkinsfile, it should be displayed each time you make a change to your repo...

Comment: It is. The problem is that with every job run the polling configuration is deleted, so next run will never be scheduled. config.xml file is overriden...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved the issue. The properties were overriden because I had another properties definition in the script: 
It looks like Jenkins will override whole set of properties nevermind if all of them are defined in the script or not.

```
/* Only keep the 10 most recent builds. */
properties([[$class  : 'BuildDiscarderProperty',strategy: [$class: 'LogRotator', numToKeepStr: '10']]])
```

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _I had another properties definition in the script_ ? Glad you found a solution and your question looks interesting so could you please provide a liitle bit more information please ? It could probably help others :)

Comment: It means that apart from the "clickable" configuration in the jenkins job (where Poll SCM option was selected) I put some configuration into the Jenkinsfile (in the code sample above). I didn't know that it will override the rest of configuration. This is my first Jenkinsfile script and it contains a lot of copy-pastes from all over Internet ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but I'd recommend switching to the github webhook to trigger a build.

From the guy who started Jenkins, [polling must die](http://kohsuke.org/2011/12/01/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-from-a-git-hook)

Comment: I know, I've already read it... It would be ideal. The problem is that I'm using Bitbucket. And I'm struggling with the configuration of the webhook. I did it once and it worked as a charm but it was long before the pipeline. And now, when I try to do it again with this pipeline build it doesn't work (Bitbucket plugin tries to find a project in Jenkins configured with the repo url but fails to find it...)